# Modify value in list inside list

Tags: python, list

I want to remove the `]` from each item on this list (and later compare the hours and obtain the average time between each hour). How can I do so?
The list is as it follows:

`['21:35:32]', '21:35:40]', '21:36:04]', '21:37:24]', '21:37:33]', '21:37:47]', '17:26:30]', '17:26:33]', '17:26:40]'`, etc...

So far I coded this:

```
getfile = open('_Echat.txt', 'r', errors="ignore")
read = getfile.read()

bigstring = ''.join(read)
result = [line.split(' ') for line in bigstring.split('[')]
horas = []
for x in result:
    if len(x) > 2:
        horas.append(x[1])
print(horas)
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear. I don't know what do you mean by comparing hours. But I wrote the code which will give you the list of hours.

```py
#use this on read data from file
hours = [int(read[i].replace(']', '').split(':')[0]) for i in range(len(read))]

#To get minutes and seconds use `[1]` and `[2]` respectively in the above code
```

this is the output for given data

```json
[21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 17, 17, 17]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two very easy solutions with list comprehension:

```
listing = ['21:35:32]', '21:35:40]', '21:36:04]', '21:37:24]', '21:37:33]', '21:37:47]', '17:26:30]', '17:26:33]', '17:26:40]']

#replace character you do not want - better option
newlist = [x.replace(']', '') for x in listing]
#select only wanted part of string you need - only if all are similar and you know len
newlist2 = [x[0:8] for x in listing]
```

Both end up with list:

```
['21:35:32', '21:35:40', '21:36:04', '21:37:24', '21:37:33', '21:37:47', '17:26:30', '17:26:33', '17:26:40']
```

This way you get time string, to achieve hours only, second approach is easy to use:

```
hours = [int(x[0:2]) for x in listing]
#[21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 17, 17, 17]
```

This is a little bit simpler than in the another answer, you don't need to care about rest of the string (in case you don't need to know minutes etc.)

And finally the mean:

```
import statistics 
print(round(statistics.mean(hours)))
#20
```